# How to Enable Single Sign-On (SSO) for SAP Business One?

Tags: sapb1

i required sap business one web access login via active directory users. it's possible are not.

If possible then how to connect the and enable sso using active directory in sap business one.

Anyone know please share me,
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable SSO from ControlCenter https://server:40000/ControlCenter/
and go to Security tab.